# Under GDPR Data Processing Officer's email address bounces - what to do?

Tags: gdpr

In 2007 (>11 years ago) I registered for an (otherwise legitimate) business SMS newsletter. Now, when GDPR is live I wanted to use my rights to finally stop them sending me these texts.

So I had sent an email to their official Data Processing Officer email address, but their server responded with a generic failure message:

```
<inspektorODO@vistulagroup.pl>: host
vistulagroup-pl.mail.protection.outlook.com[213.19 9.154.170] said: 451
4.7.500 Server busy. Please try again later from [213.180.142.153].
(AS77713200) [DB5EUR01FT011.eop-EUR01.prod.protection.outlook.c om] (in
reply to end of DATA command)
```

This email address was mentioned as the only contact info in their GDPR newsletter.

How can I deliver my request to stop processing my data?

Comment: You can try again tomorrow, maybe it is just a technical problem. Otherwise they don't comply with article 13.1a GDPR, and you can complain at the supervisory authority.

Comment: Their email address format seems for be first.last, so you could try the name here directly? https://www.vistulagroup.pl/biuro-prasowe/kontakt-1 (and tell him that his ODO address doesn't work). But if you didn't want their newsletters, did you really have to wait for GDPR to ask them to unsubscribe you?

Comment: @Rup - thanks. I have tried that approach and that finally worked. At least a human responded with something.